# Python 3.5.2 Запись в текстовой файл результатов из Shell

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, запись

Есть следующий простой скриптик.

```
print("""Приветствую, друг мой!
Ниже я предлагаю ввести тебе числа, и увидеть очевидный ответ.
Не суди строго, это всего лишь мой первый скриптик на Python!)
Итак, сделай следующее:""")

print("Пожалуйста, введи любое цифровое 'Значение один' и нажми Enter:")  
while True:  
try:  `введите сюда код`
    x=float(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Это не цифровое значение, попробуй снова:")
    continue
else:
    break
print("Пожалуйста введи любое цифровое 'Значение два' и нажми Enter:")
while True:
try:
    y=float(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Это не цифровое значение, попробуй снова:")
    continue
else:
    break
print("Вопрос: 'Значение один' не равен 'Значению два'?")
if x!=y:
print("Да - не равен")
else:
print("Нет, равен")
print("Конец. Спасибо.\nP.S. Не суди строго)")
```

При выполнении пишет всё аккуратно в интерпритаторе:
[image: Python Shell]

Но при попытке записи данных скрипта в текстовый файл, предположим так

```
a=("""Приветсвую, друг мой!
Ниже я предлагаю ввести тебе числа, и увидеть очевидный ответ.
Не суди строго, это всего лишь мой первый скриптик на Python!)
Итак, сделай следующее:""")
b=("Пожалуйста, введи любое цифровое 'Значение один' и нажми Enter:")
file=open("C:\Борода.txt","w")
file.writelines(a)
file.writelines(b)
print(a)
print(b)
while True:
    try:
        x=float(input())
    except ValueError:
    print("Это не цифровое значение, попробуй снова:")
    continue
    else:
        break
    file.writelines(x)
....
```

(и т.д.)
в текстовый документ всё пишется в строку, и не записывается переменная `x` (и в дальнейшем тоже).

Вопросы:

1. Как сделать так, что бы в файл записывалась переменная?
2. Как сделать так, что бы в текстовый файл писался читабельный тест из окна Python Shell?

Comment: У вас минимум три несвязанных вопроса: 1- как float `x` в файл записать (не нужно для этого целый скрипт без разбора приводить—старайтесь [минимальный пример кода использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) 2- как новые строки в вывод добавить 3- [как перенаправить стандартный  вывод в файл.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279) Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос—если необходимо задайте несколько отдельных Stack Overflow вопросов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Учту рекомендации по оформлению. Так же рассмотрю советы из комментариев, попробую разобраться и применить. Я только недавно начал изучать Python, очень интересно. Извиняюсь если вопрос был "от чайника".

Comment: Мой *комментарий* показывает *путь* как можно улучшить ваш Stack Overflow вопрос. Дело не в простоте вопроса, а его полезности для будущих 90%+ посетителей из поисковика, с тем же вопросом. Посмотрите [мой ответ на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616/23044)

Comment: Спасибо. На досуге ознакомлюсь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. привести тип переменной с строковому

   ```
   file.writelines(str(x) +"\n")
   ```
2. [writelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) по умолчанию не добавляет перенос строки, нужно добавить их вручную

   ```
   file.writelines(a + "\n")
   file.writelines(b + "\n")
   ```

   для сохранения переносов внутри строковой переменной нужно проставить эту [escape-последовательность](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) внутри строковой переменной:

   ```
   a=("""Приветсвую, друг мой!\nНиже я предлагаю ввести тебе числа...""")
   ```

Comment: Лучше: `print(x)` использовать вместо `file.writelines(str(x)+"\n")` в этом примере, так как автор хочет стандартный вывод перенаправить в файл (один из вариантов: `with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file): ...`—см. ссылку в комментарии выше)